# Not able to use aggregate with Splitter in Camel Version 3.20.0

Tags: apache-camel

I am not able to use aggregate with Splitter in Camel Version 3.20.0.

**completionSize** is not getting considered when I am using Aggregate inside the Splitter

Splitter is splitting in batches of 1 only, but I want to split Json array of large size say 100 into batches of 10.

Below is my code snippet

```
<bean id="myStrategy" class="org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy"/>

<route>
    < from uri : splitter>
    <split>
        <jsonpath>$</jsonpath>
        <aggregate aggregationStrategy= "myStrategy"
                   completionSize="10" completionTimeout="1000">
            <correlationExpression>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </correlationExpression>
            <marshal>
                <json></json>
            </marshal>
        </aggregate
    </split>
    < to uri : transformer>
</route>
```

Can you please suggest how to achieve this.